# IEEE.754 in ARM Assebmly algorithm giving unexpected results

Tags: assembly, floating-point, arm, gdb

I am trying to implement a simple algorithm to add to floating point numbers using the IEEE.754 floating point notation. I have gotten quite far in the algorithm, but it does not give me the expected results

This is how the algorithm is looking so far. Only trying to add **1.0 + 1.0** at this point. The expected result is for the R0 register to be **0x40000000** at the point of hitting BX lr, which is the end of the program. The result I get now is a disappointing **0x40800000**.

I compile with:
arm-none-eabi-as -g -o float.o float.s
arm-none-eabi-ld -0 float float.o

and then i run with Qemu
qemu-arm -g 30005 ./part5

and step through with gdb
gdb-multiarch
file ./float
target remote:30005

step through as normal with gdb

```
.section .data

@ Constants
exponent_mask: .word 0x7F800000

@ The two numbers we want to add
num1:   .word   0x3f800000
num2:   .word   0x3f800000 

.section .text
.global main

main:
@ Load numbers directly
    LDR r0, =num1
    LDR r0, [r0]
    LDR r1, =num2
    LDR r1, [r1]



@ Load constant for exponent extraction just once
    LDR r12, =exponent_mask
    LDR r12, [r12]

@ Extract exponents
    AND r2, r0, r12
    AND r3, r1, r12
    LSR r2, r2, #23
    LSR r3, r3, #23

@ Clear the exponent parts
    BIC r4, r0, r12
    BIC r5, r1, r12

@ Add the implicit 1 to the fractions
    ORR r4, r4, #0x00800000  
    ORR r5, r5, #0x00800000  


@ Align exponents and adjust fractions
    CMP r2, r3
    BGT largerExponent

@ r3 has larger exponent
    SUB r6, r3, r2
    LSR r4, r4, r6
    MOV r2, r3
    B fractionsAligned

largerExponent:
    SUB r6, r2, r3
    LSR r5, r5, r6

fractionsAligned:
    ADD r4, r4, r5   @ Add aligned fractions

@ Normalize if needed
    TST r4, #0x01000000
    BEQ doneNormalize
    LSR r4, r4, #1
    ADD r2, r2, #1

doneNormalize:
    @ Construct the final number
    LSL r2, r2, #23
    ORR r0, r4, r2

BX lr
```

At the end of the program, the register values look like this:
[Reg values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pZyz.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After adding and normalizing, your code does not remove the leading 1 bit.

Comment: Wow, just like that it worked. Thank you very much, impressive how you saw it so fast!